How can I remove rust stains from a cultured quartz countertop surface?
I have an otherwise-new slab that was gathering dust [and assorted metal tools apparently!] for some time.   We can see the outlines of two rusted tools here. One is a utility knife blade and the other is anyone's guess.

Is there a way to hide/fix these deep stains/blemishes?  I'm presuming a bit of scuffing and then applying a small amount of some finishing compound.  Does that exist for a nearly-white quartz[-like] surface?   What would I expect the quality of the result to be?  I'm trying to decide whether to use this countertop for a different bathroom [vs buying everything new].

Well Quartz (or probably a quartz-like composite) is dangerous to work with: the dust is silica-laden and highly dangerous. Even wearing two N95 masks and outside it immediately bothered me seriously to take a (powerful!) router to it.  So I won't be doing the cutouts that had been planned.  My lungs /health are of more value to me than a perfect countertop setup.
But the flipside is .. if you already have it .. man is it tough. And forgiving.  It took single digit seconds hand-sanding with 60-grade to completely wipe out each stain.  I did not even need to followup with a higher (lighter) grade sandpaper afterwards: the spots are completely smooth.
Look ma! No rust!


I'm curious whether you tried any chemical rust removers (CLR, navy gel) before getting physical with it. Considering that it was only a surface stain those seem viable without risking a change in the sheen.

Vinegar can be used as a safer rust remover. Acetic acid plus iron oxide yields water-soluble iron acetate. That's become my go-to for tools and other things I can immerse for a while. But I hesitated to make suggestions due to the risk this wasn't actually quartz.

@keshlam. That's a good suggestion: I did not know vinegar (acetic acid!) can take the rust out.  If you want to make an answer, I'd also upvote it.

@isherwood. I have one of those compounds in transit from Amazon. But you'd be [really] surprised how tough this stuff is. For expanding the hole I tried a regular router, then a monster router (12Amps) and they barely touched it. Then a diamond blade cutoff and finally an electric circular saw with a diamond blade. Even so, when it came to the sanding, I started out quite light on the sanding. This technique worked fine and is a viable approach for this material [given the prior experience with its hardness/toughness].
